# Get grammatical conjugation with GermaNLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

What I can see in the [documentation of GermaNLTK](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rdn0hOnJNcOBWEZgipdDfSyjJdnv_sinuAUSDSpiQns/edit?hl=en#) (an integration of NLTK and [GermaNet](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/GermaNet/)) is the possibility to lemmatize German words correctly.

```
>>> gwl.lemmatize('geht')
'gehen'
```

or

```
>>> gwl.lemmatize('kann')
'können'
```

It's good to know the infinitive, but I want more. What I actually want is to get the information about grammatical conjugation. For example something like this:

```
>>> gwl.grammatical_conjugation('geht')
{'gehen':'3. Person Singular'}
```

or

```
>>> gwl.grammatical_conjugation('kann')
{'können': ['1. Person Singular', '3. Person Singular']}
```

How would you get the information about the grammatical conjugation?

Answer (score 1):

I think GermaNLTK can't do this. Instead I'd suggest to make use of the python module [**pattern**](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-de)

```
pip install pattern
```

Here you can see the check if a word is *1. person singular* (`1sg`) or *3. person singular* (`3sg`)

```
>>> from pattern.de import conjugate
>>> wort1 = "bin"
>>> wort2 = "kann"
>>> wort3 = "geht"
>>>
>>> wort1 == conjugate(wort1, "1sg")
True
>>> wort1 == conjugate(wort1, "3sg")
False
>>> wort2 == conjugate(wort2, "1sg")
True
>>> wort2 == conjugate(wort2, "3sg")
True
>>> wort3 == conjugate(wort3, "1sg")
False
>>> wort3 == conjugate(wort3, "3sg")
True
```

powerful and efficient.